# this.pay() is not a function

Tags: javascript, angular

When the payment widget is called, after a successful transaction, the `pay` function should be executed, but in the console I see the error `this.pay() is not a function`. What could be the problem?

A widget function

```
  openWidget() {
    // @ts-ignore
    let widget = new PaytureWidget({
      Key : "Merchant",
      Amount : this.model.sum,
      Product : "Payment №1",
      Domain : 2,
      OnTransactionCompleted : function(success: any) { 
        this.pay()
      }
    })
  }
```

And `pay()` if needed:

```
  async pay() {
    const mapProduct = (product: ShoppingCartProduct): UserProduct => {
      return {
        productId: product.id,
        count: product.multiplicator,
        price: product.price
      }
    }

    const userProducts = this.sumupProducts.map(mapProduct)
    const accountBalance = await this.userProductsDataService.addProducts(userProducts);
    if (accountBalance !== -1) {

      this.paymentEventService.emitSuccess(accountBalance);
      this.model.products = this.model.products.filter(x => !x.checked);
      this.sumupProducts = [];
      this.model.sum = this.getShoppingCartSum();
      this.eventService.emit(StarOneEventType.ChangedNumberOfProductsInShoppingCart);
    } else {
      this.paymentEventService.emitFail("Payment Fail");
    }
  }
```

Comment: try using a arrow function
```OnTransactionCompleted: (success: any) => { this.pay() }```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that the **this** keyword inside the OnTransactionCompleted callback function refers to the callback function itself, rather than the component where the **openWidget** function is defined. This means that **this.pay** is not a valid method because it doesn't exist on the callback function.

One way to fix this issue would be to use an arrow function for the OnTransactionCompleted callback, like this:

```
  openWidget() {
  // @ts-ignore
  let widget = new PaytureWidget({
    Key : "Merchant",
    Amount : this.model.sum,
    Product : "Payment №1",
    Domain : 2,
    OnTransactionCompleted : (success: any) => {
      this.pay();
    }
  });
}
```

Arrow functions use the value of the **this** keyword from the surrounding context, so in this case, **this** will refer to the component where the **openWidget** function is defined, and **this.pay** will be a valid method.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one

```
OnTransactionCompleted : (success: any) => { 
    this.pay()
  }
```